# Failure to Update record CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am currently trying to update my user before sending an email which will have a confirm link with a resetkey for the user to reset the password.

The problem is that the user is not updating whilst the key is being generated.

the code can be seen hereunder

```
public function forgotpassword() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $mail = $this->request->data['ContactDetail']['email'];
            $data = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('ContactDetail.email' => $mail)));

        if (!$data) {
            $message = __('No Such E-mail address registerd with us ');
            $this->Session->setFlash($message);
        } else {
            $data['User']['resetkey'] = Security::hash(mt_rand(),'md5',true);
            debug($data);
            if ($this->User->saveAssociated($data)) {
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            }
            else {
                  $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be updated. Please, try again.'));
            }
            $key = $data['User']['resetkey'];
            $id = $data['User']['id'];
            $mail = $data['ContactDetail']['email'];
            $email = new CakeEmail('default');
            $email->to($mail);
            $email->from("xxxx@yahoo.com");
            $email->emailFormat('html');
            $email->subject('Password reset instructions from');
            $email->viewVars(array('key' => $key, 'id' => $id, 'rand' => mt_rand()));
            $email->template('reset');
            if ($email->send('reset')) {
                $message = __('Please check your email for reset instructions.');
                $this->Session->setFlash($message);
            } else {
                $message = __('Something went wrong with activation mail. Please try later.');
                $this->Session->setFlash($message);
            }
        }
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I checked the execution log of MySQL but all I am seeing are selects no updates or even inserts.

This is probably something very dumb but I can't understand why it doesn't say anything.

Comment: Why do you use `saveAssociated` method for update single field? Something like this would be easier: `$this->User->updateAll(array('User.resetkey'=>$hash),array('User.id'=>$userId));`

Comment: @walkingRed your comment was enough to answer my question if you would place it as an answer I would accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `saveAssociated` method for update single field?

Something like this would be easier:

```
$this->User->updateAll(
    array( 'User.resetkey' => $hash ),
    array( 'User.id' => $userId )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 $this->User->saveMany($data, array('deep' => true));
```

When saving. Also

```
 if (empty($data)) {...
```

Might be a safer way to go

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you-

```
$this->User->id = $data['User']['id'];
if ($this->User->save($data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
}else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be updated. Please, try again.'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug like:

```
            if ($this->User->saveAssociated($data)) {
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            }
            else {
                  $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be updated. Please, try again.'));
            }
            $log=$this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($log);exit;
```

Comment: I did that and I actually mentioned it that all I am getting are select statements.